# system boot 4.15.0-47-generi Tue Apr 23 11:44 still running ( .last with rails c )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

When I open Ruby on Rails console, with `rails c`, I can directly type `.last` without any Model.

I get something like a `log`.

What does `.last` mean (when it's standalone) and why does it work in `rails c` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.last` command show a listing of last logged in users. You can use UNIX command with a **.** before command in you're rails console.

**last** is a UNIX command to list all logged in users of system